# How can you wire a 555 timer to gradually decrease sound volume?

Tags: 555

Say you are taking in an audio input from a headphone speaker and you would like the audio to gradually decrease until inaudible.

Are there better, also very common chips that can do this more reliably?

Let's say you wanted the volume to decrease over 1 minute?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that 555 timer is the right chip for the job? While I'm sure someone could do this with a 555, it doesn't seem to be at all appropriate. Also, what resets/triggers this volume decrease?

Comment: I don't know if it's the right chip to do the job but it's the only timer chip I've learned about. What would be more appropriate? I'll probably have a jumper wire connecting my circuit to an audio input from a headphone jack

Comment: A 555 does its "timing" using a resistor and a capacitor that is outside the chip. So having the 555 buys you nothing. The 555 can switch at 1/3 or 2/3 the capacitor voltage, but that is too far from your goal of max or min volume to be of much use either. A better approach might involve an RC circuit and an FET.

Comment: You might want to read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm45974142268336 "If what you want is to do Y, you should ask that question without pre-supposing the use of a method that may not be appropriate. Questions of this form often indicate a person who is not merely ignorant about X, but confused about what problem Y they are solving and too fixated on the details of their particular situation."

Comment: Are you using an op-amp or any sort of gain control already? Or is is straight to the Analog Input?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, one of the least fussy solutions would be a small MCU and a digipot. Specifically, a log digital potentiometer designed for audio (so that it switches on zero crossings), and just about any microcontroller. 
Most digital pots are controlled via I2C (or occasionally SPI).

You can trigger the "fade" however you like (button, etc), and you have very good control of fade length and linearity. You can even do stereo with nearly gain-matched channels (there are digipots specifically for stereo audio).

This way, no analog weirdness, programmable fade characteristics, flexible triggering (you still haven't said how you want it to trigger), and basically two parts (plus a power source and a smidgen of passives).

Comment: Why bother with a digipot? Go straight for a i2c/spi controlled op-amp, like https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/DS4420.html Cut out the middleman.

Comment: @Passerby Ah good point. I forgot about those!

Comment: Just wanted to mention Burr-Brown Stereo Audio Volume Control chips: PGA2311 (+/-5V), PGA2310 and PGA2320 (+/-15V). They all come in SOIC and DIP packages, are controlled via SPI and have range from −95.5dB up to +31.5dB.

Answer (score 1):

A technique that can achieve what you want is passing your audio signal through a voltage-controlled switch. The control voltage should toggle the switch on and off at a frequency f_c over the audible spectrum and the duty cycle should change progressively between 100% to 0%.

From a signal processing point of view, you are effectively multiplying your signal by a variable duty-cycle rectangular signal exhibiting the values 0 and 1. The spectrum of this signal is a sum of terms of the form A_n·X(f-n·f_c) and the A_0 term is what you are interested in. A low-pass filter should be used to filter out the higher terms, but this may be unnecessary if the elements after your circuit already have a low-pass response.

There are many ways to achieve this. An analog switch could be controlled by any device able to produce a variable duty-cycle signal. A 555 can certainly produce a PWM (Pulse-Width Modulation) signal, but you would also have to generate the linear (or logarithmic) decaying function. A simple microcontroller could do this job very easily.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hacky way to do this would be a 555 or 556 Timer as a PWM source to a LED. Which is then tied to a CDS LDR (light dependent resistor) inline with the audio source, like a pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9L5A0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The preferred way to do it would be two LEDS/LDR combos, with two PWM sources that are inverse to each other.

See http://practicalusage.com/vc-1-digitalmidi-volume-control/ for a project that did this.

You need to couple the LED and LDR together. Electrical tape always works. This is done professionally though dedicated parts like  photoresistive opto-isolators.

[image]

Comment: If F 555 is big this will give really low distortion.

Comment: Have you tried this? LDRs are very slow devices. Some of them have rise times in the order of tens of ms (!), which makes this approach not usable with fast signals.

Comment: @petrus no, but there are commercial opti-resistor for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

As others have stated a 555 timer is probably not the best option.  I think a better option would be to use a transistor and an RC network to act as a choke:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTb6TR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, push the button to start at 'max volume'.  As the RC network discharges, the lower NPN becomes more and more resistive, until it completely cuts off and allows no more volume.

IF you want it to always have some volume, instead connect C1 and R2's GROUND terminal to a seperate 0.6V potential, which you can generate with a Resistor + Diode.  This is a voltage reference will will keep the voltage at barely on even after a long time.

Tweaking the value of R2/C1 will change how quickly the signal becomes quiet.
Tweaking the ratio of R1 to R3 will increase/decrease the gain; which you will want to do depending on the magnitude of your input voltage signal.

If you want 1 minute, the time constant is approximately 30s.  You can calculate the size of C by figuring out how much base current is provided to Q4 and how long that it will take for C1 to discharge.  Q = CV; Q = I * t

However, you should be able to simulate and just increase the size of the cap until it discharges slowly enough.

Tweaking the value of R1 will have a large effect on the output resistance, and how much power that this circuit can provide to a load.

The simulation waveforms below show the initial gain (~1, if you need actual voltage amplification decrease the size of R3 proportional to your desired change in gain)

They also show the gain over time, which falls off slowly for the first 30s then quickly until silent at 1 minute.

[image: initialgain and gain over time]

Below is minute long sim, it shows gain as time progresses.  I have zoomed at start and end.  The low resolution is because the runtime was so long, I could not get much higher resolution for a full minute reasonably.

[image: gain at start and end]

Comment: This is a terrible design! Have you ever actually built and tested it?

Comment: Where do I start? No bias for Q2. High output impedance. Applying 5V directly to BE junction of Q1. Show us your simulation.

Comment: You can bypass the simulation time by hitting edit on the question, then edit the schematic. Once your back in circuit lab, simulate away.

Comment: I tweaked your schematic so that it actually simulates. Is that your final answer? The distortion in the output is terrible, even when running at full volume (and it gets much worse as it cuts off), and the gain drops to zero in about half a second.

Comment: Added biasing, decoupling cap, diode reference (as originally referenced).  Simulations as well.  If you need lower output resistance just add a second stage to buffer (common collector maybe??)  The question was not how to provide large drive strength but how to quiet over 'about a minute'